# Translating SQL Server code in to MS Access SQL code - DISTINCT issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have a piece of code in SQL Server which I need to use in MS Access, however am currently having difficulty translating it due to the inability to use DISTINCT on specific columns/aggregated functions.

I've tried using a subquery to solve the issue however am finding that the COUNT of parent case ID is identical to the count of child case ID (as there can be multiple child cases with the same parent case ID).

This is the code that achieves the desired results in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
[Master_ID]
,COUNT(DISTINCT [parent_file_id]) AS Number_of_parent_files
,COUNT([Child_ID]) AS Number_of_child_files
FROM [EXAMPLE_TABLE]
GROUP BY [Master_ID]
ORDER BY 1
```

I would expect to see a list of all Master IDs, the corresponding number of parent file IDs they have, and the lower level detail of how many child files are within all of the parent file IDs. Currently when inputting to Access I am unable to get the lower level detail without it affecting the parent file ID.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to group by in a subquery and then count the results. As a result you'll have to aggregate your `number_of_child_files` field twice to collect the count.

```
SELECT 
    Master_ID, 
    Count(parent_file_id) as number_of_parent_files, 
    SUM(child_id_count) as number_of_child_files
FROM (
        SELECT 
            Master_ID, 
            parent_file_id, 
            count(Child_ID) as child_id_count
        FROM EXAMPLE_TABLES
        GROUP BY Master_ID, parent_file_id
    ) as s
GROUP BY Master_ID
ORDER BY Master_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe handle the Distinct separate from the Count(*).  Can you try changing the following:

From:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT [parent_file_id]) AS Number_of_parent_files
```

To:

```
(Select Count(*) As cnt From (Select Distinct parent_file_id From [EXAMPLE_TABLE] As tbl)) AS Number_of_parent_files
```